# I'm having an issue making/updating HTML elements.- Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, refresh

I've taken a look at this code I'm writing over and over, but can't seem to find what the problem is. What I'm trying to do is have a sliding bar that appears on the screen, like a health/mana bar.
Here's the function I'm using to create a bar:

```
function makeBar(max,color,place){
    b=new Object();
    len=bar.length;
    bar.push(b);
    b.index=len;
    b.place=place;
    b.color=color;
    b.max=max;
    b.val=max;
    b.print=function(){
        this.place.innerHTML+="<div id='bar"+this.index+"' style='display:inline-block;text-align:center;height:40px;width:200px;border:3px outset black;'><div id='subBar"+this.index+"' style='font-size:20pt;height:34px;width:1px;background:"+this.color+";border:3px outset "+this.color+";'></div></div>";
        this.container=document.getElementById('bar'+this.index);
        this.content=document.getElementById('subBar'+this.index);
    }
    b.refresh=function(){
        this.content.style.width=(this.val/this.max)*194+"px";
    }
    b.print();
}
```

So it makes and 'prints' the bar perfectly.
But when I try using

```
bar[0].refresh();
```

It does nothing, unless bar[0] is the only bar.
Basically, only the last created bar can use its own refresh() method successfully.
Can anyone help me?
Thanx every1

Comment: Could you plz create a fiddle demonstrating the issue? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Has object B refresh function? You can try by making "b" as global variable instead of using it locally.

i.e.

```
 var b;
function makeBar(max,color,place){
 b=new Object();
 len=bar.length;
 //bar.push(b);  don't push here
 b.index=len;
 b.place=place;
 b.color=color;
 b.max=max;
 b.val=max;
 b.print=function(){
    this.place.innerHTML+="<div id='bar"+this.index+"' style='display:inline-block;text-align:center;height:40px;width:200px;border:3px outset black;'><div id='subBar"+this.index+"' style='font-size:20pt;height:34px;width:1px;background:"+this.color+";border:3px outset "+this.color+";'></div></div>";
    this.container=document.getElementById('bar'+this.index);
    this.content=document.getElementById('subBar'+this.index);
}
b.refresh=function(){
    this.content.style.width=(this.val/this.max)*194+"px";
}
b.print();
}
```

If you want to use single instance of object b then don't use array. Call `b.refresh()` directly.

Comment: when I use Chrome's 'Inspect Element' after creating 2 instances of bar and type in bar[0] and bar[1] respectively into the console, bar[0] has div#bar0 and div#subBar0 as it's container and content properties respectively, which are real elements on the page, but when I hover my mouse over it, it doesn't highlight the element as it does with bar[1]. The same is true if I create lots of bars. Only the last bar object created will do this. And I have no idea why...